# QT error : :-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: xmlpatterns axcontainer

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt5, qt-creator

I have tried to run a project which I am not sure exactly which QT5 version, I am currently trying it on QT5.9.9. And it only has one build error which is :-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: xmlpatterns axcontainer . I have seen online that I many need to install the module or add it via CONFIG . However I cannot for the life me find out how to install a QT Module or whether I even need to. I know that between the QT 5 version there is little difference but does QT 5.9.9 even have this xmlpatterns axcontainer and whether I might just not have the right version. I really need any guidance on how i could go about this problem. I am on Windows 10 using Minigw .

Comment: Is there any reason why are you using such an old version of Qt? If you do not want to migrate to Qt6 then there is still version Qt 5.15.x. I would however advice against using xmlpatterns since they were deprecated in Qt 5.13. If you use it, you code will not be future proof. I would suggest searching for some other external XML validating library. And regarding axcontainer, you need to install ActiveQt library. I do not know how to do it in old Qt5 installers, but in Qt6 it is listed in Additional Libraries section if you use Qt Maintenance Tool.

Comment: thank you very much, I used qt 5.12 and it worked